# Execute only last block of queue

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Does grand central dispatch have any features to execute only the most recent block of a dispatch-queue? Imagine this situations: there are *many* work items. After each work item, we dispatch a block to inform the user about the current status. So for every work-item there will be a 'refresh-ui-block'. After executing one of these refresh-ui-blocks, all other items of this queue can be discarded except the last one. the last one can be executed to refresh the UI.

Does grand central dispatch has this feature or is there something like a default implementation of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a modified producer/consumer-solution limited to a buffer size of 1 and discarding every item pushed if buffer is full. 
Added a block variable in header file:

```
void(^_refreshBlock)(void);
```

and doing something like this in implementation

```
- (void)doRefresh
{
    if (!_refreshBlock)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&_refreshMutex);
        // get a weak self (a strong self will lead to a retain cycle)
        __weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;
        _refreshBlock = ^(void)
        {
                [weakSelf privateRefresh];
        };
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&_refreshMutex);

        dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(delay,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
            if (_refreshBadgeBlock)
            {
                void(^work)(void) = _refreshBadgeBlock;
                _refreshBadgeBlock = nil;
                work();
            }
        });
    }
    // else : _refreshBadgeBlock already allocated and will run later
}
```